# How to open all tables in a SAS library within a LOOP?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

m trying to do an automatic loop in SAS EG in order to access the libraries and their tables to profile the data.

I start listing my libraries and tables with the following code:

```
proc sql;
create table DIC as
select * from dictionary.tables where libname = 'HYUI;
quit ;
```

Then, I loop as follows, but I encounter an error.

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT  count(*) 
        INTO 
            :n_var
        FROM work.DIC;
QUIT;

%put  'n_var=' &n_var;

%DO I = 1 %TO 2;

    data _null_;
        set work.DIC;

        if _n_= &I;
        call symput('memname', memname);
        call symput('libname', libname);

    run;

    proc sql;
        create table 'x_DIC' as
            select *, &memname as nome_tabela
                from &libname;
    quit;



proc append data=&memname base=work.PROF;
    run;

%end;
```

The error I have is the following: **ERROR: File WORK.HYUI.DATA does not exist.**

But in fact I have this library. How do I overcome this error?

Comment: You may find these helpful: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Library-Datasets-Summary-Macro-DATA-SPECS/ta-p/544757  and this one https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Demographic-Table-and-Subgroup-Summary-Macro-TABLEN/ta-p/634030

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing this:

```
select *, &memname as nome_tabela 
  from &libname;
```

You can't select columns from a libname; you select columns from a table.  A library is a folder in Windows, or perhaps an Excel workbook - while a dataset is a file, or an Excel worksheet.  The dataset, or table, is what has columns and data, the library contains datasets.

It's not obvious what you're trying to actually do here, but I would guess perhaps you're trying to get at the data from `dictionary.columns` or `dictionary.tables`?  Most likely you can do what you're trying to do directly.  You also definitely have easier ways of doing [whatever] for each table, than this convoluted method, but I think you'll want to ask a new question where you explain what you want to do, and then we can suggest better ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS`.

Or perhaps all the tables in a library has the same data structure, AND you want to stack all those tables into a single table ?

You will want to explain this more

```
    proc sql;
        create table 'x_DIC' as
            select *, &memname as nome_tabela
                from &libname;
    quit;
```

- `Proc SQL` tables names are not single quoted
- &memname is not a string literal, the macro symbol resolution should be coded inside double quotes.
- `from` needs to be from a table with construct ., NOT a bare libref.

At a minimum your code might need to be

```
        create table x_DIC as
            select *, "&memname" as nome_tabela
                from &libname..nome_tablea;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select ... from xxx` will indeed be interpreted as `select ... from WORK.xxx`, because `WORK` is the default library. You want to select from a table, so the *table name* is essential, and that is `&memname`. the libname is needed too, because your table is not in WORK: `select ... from &libname..&lmemname`. Mind the double dot: the first is to close the macro variable and the second to separate the lib and the member.

#### Anyway, there is a much briefer way to program this;

```
proc sql;
  select 'select *, "'|| memname ||'" as nome_tabela from HYUI.'|| memname
  into: select_them separated by ' union '
  from dictionary.tables where libname = 'HYUI;

  create table WORK.PROF as
  &select_them;
quit;
```

It will only fail if the fields in the datasets in your library don't match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do here, but if you want to append all tables into one in your work you could do something like this(assuming all tables hava the same column names and types):

I don't have SAS on my pc to test it, so forgive me if there is a typo or syntax error.

```
proc sql;
    create table tablesToAppend as select memname from sashelp.vtable where libname ='HYUI';
quit;

%let Nrows=0;

data _null_ ;
    set tablesToAppend;
    call symputx('table_'||strip(_n_),memname);
    call symputx('Nrows',_n_);
run;

%macro loop;
    data work.alltables; stop; run;
    %do i=1 %to &Nrows.;
        proc append data=work.alltables base=&&table_&i.; run;
    %end;
%mend;

%loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to address whether this is the proper plan for your actual problem, but let's go through your program and fix the syntax errors and obvious logic errors.

To use the interative %DO loop you will need to enclose at least that part of the process in a macro definition and then run the macro.  Let's just enclose the whole program you have shown in a macro.  While we are at it let's make the macro variables used local so we don't accidentally modify any existing macro variables with the same names.

```
%macro test;
%local n_var i libname memname;
```

Fix the missing closing single quote in your first query. Also you can take advantage of the automatic macro variable SQLOBS to get the count of members in the library immediately after creating the DIC dataset.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table DIC as
  select * from dictionary.tables where libname = 'HYUI'
;
%let n_var = &sqlobs ;
quit ;
```

Now loop over all of the datasets instead of just the first two.  You can use the FIRSTOBS= and OBS= dataset options to process just the one observation from DIC.  Instead of using the ancient CALL SYMPUT() function use the more modern CALL SYMPUTX() function so that macro variable values are created without trailing spaces.

```
%DO I = 1 %TO &n_var ;

data _null_;
  set work.DIC (firstobs=&i obs=&i);
  call symputx('memname', memname);
  call symputx('libname', libname);
run;
```

Now in the step to create a copy of data with the added nome_tabela variable make sure to use a valid name for the dataset, set a length for the created variable, and reference the actual dataset using both the libref and member name.

```
proc sql;
 create table x_DIC as
  select *, "&memname" as nome_tabela length=32
      from &libname..&memname
 ;
quit;
```

In the PROC APPEND step make sure to append from the dataset you just created.  Add the FORCE option so that if WORK.PROF does not exist it is created the first time through the loop.

```
proc append data=x_DIC base=work.PROF force;
run;
```

Now close the %DO loop and the macro definition and then call the macro.

```
%end;
%mend test;

%test;
```